# mac OS PyQt5 image not found

Tags: python, macos, qt, path, pyqt

I am trying to install PyQt5 on macOS Sierra. I succesfully installed `qt-unified-mac-x64-2.0.3-online` than I used `pip3 install pyqt5` to install PyQt. 
My $PYTHONPATH is `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages:`

When I try to run basic Qt app

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

qtCreatorFile = "dialog.ui" # Enter file here.

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I already googled and found some solutions but nothing worked (or I am too tired right now X_X)

Edit:
I tryied to install into python2.x but I have same issue.
Thanks for any help.

**SOLVED**
I insert PATH directly into sys.path

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/')
```

and now everything works fine

Comment: Did you find any other way around this, or was the only solution using sys.path? I'm going through a similar pain...

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't find any other solutions. This solution (updating sys.path) worked for me.

Comment: It's weird, I'm seeing something similar for the same libs - pythonpath is supposed to work like the sys.path.append/insert. I'll try the sys.path today, hopefully that'll point it to the right .so files. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Try it, good luck @Tiago :)

Comment: Sadly no luck :( this is what I'm stuck with, in case you have ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512147/incompatible-library-version-pyqt5-qtcore-so-requires-version-5-7-0-or-later-b

Comment: It keeps looking in var/folders/5s/n0myy_ld6md94mtv46fg1v08q6m2lv/T/_MEIsYvcBC/PyQt5.QtCore.so I don't know why. I've tried import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')